# What technology used in this website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://brightmedia.pl/?lang=en&site=intro

What technologies used to have the white line following on the screen when we scroll through the page?

Is it the same skills used in http://www.flyacts.com/multi-channel-app/ as the line slowly go down as we scroll through?

Comment: In jquery you have a attribute called `.scrollTop()`. I think they use something like this to detect the users position on the site and than animate the thing for that section of the website

Comment: `parallax.js` or `skrollr.js` for example.

Comment: I've added some more info to my answer, please check!

Comment: Voting to close this question as these types of questions become invalid if the site author changes his site and they contribute very little value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used mainly the canvas element!
If you have carefully looked into the following sections of the HTML you will get to know.

```
<head>...</head>
<body id="page" class="bodyEnableScroll">
<div id="bg" class="" style="width: 100%; height: 7738px;">
     <canvas id="mainBgC" height="438" width="1440" style="width: 1440px; height: 438px;"></canvas>
     <canvas id="shinesBgC" height="438" width="1440" style="width: 1440px; height: 438px;"></canvas>
     <canvas id="animationC" height="438" width="1440" style="width: 1440px; height: 438px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

So there are **mainBgC**, **shinesBgC**, **animationC** wonderfully used to do the animations and to add dynamic shines throughout the website whenever the Web pages scrolls up and down.

And all of the Text contents for each of the sections have been added using the
**textContainer0...4 divs**

And also they have used the following JS Scripts for each of the objects which shows in between the Sections when you scroll up/down:
**crown.js, heart.js, rose.js, tech.js**

And also they have used Products from the following [website](http://greensock.com/) as I got to know when I dug in. Specially the following libraries:

1. [TimelineLite](http://greensock.com/timelinelite) - For making of the Tweens, check it by yourself specially running the Demo in that page.
2. [TweenLite](http://greensock.com/tweenlite) - For tweens of the four objects, Crown, Rose, Heart and Tech.
3. So basically what I can tell is they might have used more of the plugins mentioned in this Website by [Greensock](https://greensock.com/plugins/?product_id=4921)

That's all I could give you at the moment as I could find.
Better you follow the path.

Hope this was helpful to you!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
These are some library files that are used to achieve that Kind of effect in above Sites.

    TweenLite
    TimelineLite
    ScrollToPlugin
    EasePack

You Can See the documentation and download from below:-

http://modernizr.com    
http://greensock.com/get-started-js  
https://greensock.com/ScrollToPlugin 
https://greensock.com/tweenmax  
You Could Use the Some Animation that are provided by jquery
such as easeIn our easeOut to achieve the Smooth Scrolling Effect.
You could use this library Which I use For Achieving the Same purpose as shown in the Site

http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/
```